# I'm facing an issue with payment gateway using the razorpay APIs

Tags: java, android, razorpay

I have added the live API to the `Manifest` but it is not working somehow test API is working fine. I am getting this below error

```
 {"error":{"code":"bad_request_error","description":"the id provided
does not exist"}}
```

any help would be appreciated.

I have installed the latest `SDK`, tried correcting some code, compared the code with razor pay's sample android app but still no luck. And the API is working fine with sample app; I don't see any issue with it.

```
{"error":{"code":"bad_request_error","description":"the id provided does not exist"}}
```

this is the error I am getting

Comment: how does the request look?

Answer (score 6):

remove order id provided by razor pay don't use order id while testing

option.put("order_id","order_9A")  remove this line

Comment: yes the "order id" was the problem that issue is resolved already thanks anyway for your response.

Comment: please up vote this answer for so that other people can refer to this solution. @HarikrishnaGadakari